# Is this proof of $\operatorname{Var}(\overline{x})=\frac{\sigma^2}{N}$ correct?

Tags: statistics, variance

Starting from $\operatorname{Var}(\overline{x})$ I am trying to algebraically show that it is equal to $\frac{\sigma^2}{N}$ using the fact that the variance of the sum equals to the sum of variances. I start by $$\operatorname{Var}(\overline{x})=\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\right)$$
then
$$\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N \left(\frac1N \sum_{i=1}^Nx_i-\mu\right)_i^2 = \frac1N \sum_{i=1}^N \left[\frac1{N^2} \left(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i\right)^2-\frac{2\mu}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i+\mu^2 \right]_i$$
which becomes
$$\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N \left[\overline{x}^2-2\mu \overline{x}+\mu^2\right]_i = \frac1N \sum_{i=1}^N(\overline{x}_N-\mu)_i^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{N}$$

Comment: After "then" the LHS is a random variable, but the RHS is a constant.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Are the $x_i$ iid random variables?

Comment: Yes, $x_i$ is considered to be i-th experimental error in this case.

Comment: That information should be a part of your question. Also you end up with $\sigma^2/N$ which is a constant. But on the left side of $=$ there is no constant, but a stochastic expression in $x_i$. Sorry, but it is quite a mess.

Comment: $\frac{\sigma^2}{N}$ is a constant but only for a defined sequence of $x$ values. Technically $\sigma^2$ is completely a function of $x$. Also don't be sorry for criticism, I'm thankful for it.

Comment: Are you trying to say that here $\sigma^2$ denotes the [sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance)?

Comment: No, most definetly not. Here I'm also considering $\overline{x}_N=\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i$ to change as $i \to N$ and then $\sum_{i=1}^{N}(\overline{x}_N-\mu)^2_i$ becomes the $\sigma^2$ - population variance of $\overline{x}_N$ as a variable. Maybe this clarifies something?

Comment: I am afraid not. Is my answer of any use to you?

Comment: Variance of a sum does not equal the sum of variance in general. There is an added covariance term.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X,Y$ be random variables with $\mathbb{E}X^{2}<\infty$ and
$\mathbb{E}Y^{2}<\infty$. Then we have the following rules.

- $\text{Var}\left(aX+b\right)=a^{2}\text{Var}X$
- If moreover $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $\text{Var}\left(X+Y\right)=\text{Var}X+\text{Var}Y$.

Applying this on iid $X_{1},\cdots,X_{N}$ with $\mathbb{E}X_{1}^{2}<\infty$ we find:$$\text{Var}\overline{X}=\text{Var}\frac{1}{N}\left(X_{1}+\cdots+X_{N}\right)=$$$$\frac{1}{N^{2}}\text{Var}\left(X_{1}+\cdots+X_{N}\right)=\frac{1}{N^{2}}\left[\text{Var}X_{1}+\cdots+\text{Var}X_{N}\right]=\frac{\text{Var}X_{1}}{N}$$